# Output Daffodils-Numbers with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to write a python program, first it asks you to enter two numbers, and then output all daffodil numbers between the two numbers, and it will continue run, until I enter a "q". I write a program, but it is wrong:

```
#coding=utf-8

while 1:
    try:
        x1=int(raw_input("please enter a number x1="))
        x2=int(raw_input("please enter a number x2="))
    except:
        print("please enter only numbers")
        continue
    if x1>x2:
        x1,x2=x2,x1
        pass
    for n in xrange(x1,x2):
        i=n/100
        j=n/10%10
        k=n%10
        if i*100+j*10+k==i+j**2+k**3:
            print ("%-5d")%n
        pass
```

Can somebody help? I think it should be simple, but I am not able to write it correctly.

Comment: (Daffodil number?) What problem are you having? What do you want to happen and what is happening instead? What error messages do you get?

Comment: I assume "Daffodil Number" is a translation problem.  The flowers "Narcissus" are called "Daffodils" in English but from the answers below I think this should be "Narcissistic Numbers".

Comment: sry, it should be called "Narcissus Numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to address the `quit` event.

```
while True:
    x1 = raw_input("please enter a number x1=")
    x2 = raw_input("please enter a number x2=")
    quit = ('q','Q')
    if x1 in quit or x2 in quit:
        break
    else:
        try:
            x1, x2 = int(x1), int(x2)
        except:
            print("please enter only numbers")
            continue
    # The mathematical part... (for completeness) (not my code)
    if x1>x2:
        x1,x2=x2,x1
    for n in xrange(x1,x2):
        i=n/100
        j=n/10%10
        k=n%10
        if i*100+j*10+k==i+j**2+k**3:
            print "%-5d"%n
```

The `pass` statement is used only when you don't have anything to be executed in certain **block** of code. It does nothing more, so don't use it if not needed. It is there for the sake of the code looking clean & with correct indentation.

```
if some_thing: # don't do anything
else:
    some_thing = some_thing_else
```

Note how the above if statement is syntactically incorrect. This is where `pass` comes handy. Say, you decide to write the `if` part later, till then you must provide `pass`.

```
if some_thing: # don't do anything
    pass
else:
    some_thing = some_thing_else
```

Comment: while True:
    x1 = raw_input("please enter a number x1=")
    x2 = raw_input("please enter a number x2=")
    quit = ('q','Q')
    if x1 in quit or x2 in quit:
        break
    else:
        try:
            x1, x2 = int(x1), int(x2)
        except:
            print("please enter only numbers")
            continue
    if x1>x2:
        x1,x2=x2,x1
        pass
    for n in xrange(x1,x2):
        i=n/100
        j=n/10%10
        k=n%10
        if i*100+j*10+k==i+j**2+k**3:
            print ("%-5d")%n
        pass

Comment: Please check updated answer for clarification & completeness.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've misunderstood the problem statement. Try this instead:

```
if i*100+j*10+k==i**3+j**3+k**3:
```

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number

Comment: or even better replace left hand side with `n`  but +1 all the same good catch

Comment: Yeah, there are lots of ways to improve his code (see your own fine response), but I wanted to find the minimal change.

Answer (score 1):

```
for n in xrange(x1,x2):
    digits = map(int,str(n))
    num_digits = len(digits)
    if sum(map(lambda x:x**num_digits,digits)) == n:
       print "%d is a magic number"%n
```

you will still have the issue of not being able to enter "q" since you force the input to be integers

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to know what's going on without more hints, but some issues I see right off:

1. You need to be consistent with indentation in Python. Your last `if` statement is less indented than statements above it (like the previous `if` and the `for` loop). This will cause an error. You're also using different amounts of indentation in other places, but since it's not inconsistent that's allowed (if a bad idea). Its usually best to pick one indentation standard (like four spaces) and stick with it. Often you can set your text editor to help you with this (turn on "Expand tabs to spaces" or something in the settings).
2. You've got two `pass` statements where they're unneeded or harmful. The first, after the line that has `if x1>x2: x1,x2=x2,x1` is going to cause an error. You can't have an indented "suite" of code if you've put a series of simple statements on the end of your compound statement like an `if`. Either put the assignment on its own line, indented, or get rid of the `pass`. The last `pass` at the end of the code is not an error, just unnecessary.
3. You're missing a colon at the end of your `try` statement. Every statement in Python that introduces an indented suite ends with a colon, so it should be easy to learn where they're needed.

Comment: may want to mention that in this code since he forces numeric input, it is impossible for the user to enter `q` ... that might be his whole issue ... its hard to tell

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Well, I was sticking to syntax errors, not logic errors. If the code won't run once, there's no need to worry about it running forever!

Comment: well it does run once ... and forever (or until you ctrl+c) it ... but yeah I get your point. ... all of the things you said are true and he should do them ... Im just not sure that those are his problems for this particular issue

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    x1 = raw_input("please enter a number x1=")
    x2 = raw_input("please enter a number x2=")
    quit = ('q','Q')
    if x1 in quit or x2 in quit:
        break
    else:
        try:
            x1, x2 = int(x1), int(x2)
        except:
            print("please enter only numbers")
            continue
    if x1>x2:
        x1,x2=x2,x1
        pass
    for n in xrange(x1,x2):
        i=n/100
        j=n/10%10
        k=n%10
        if i*100+j*10+k==i+j**2+k**3:
            print ("%-5d")%n
        pass
```

i have it! thx to Ashish! it is exactly what i want! and i will quit wenn i enter q! thx a lot!